# Loading Vision Transformer Model After Changing Its Classifier Head

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, vision-transformer

I added more layers in the classifier head of the VIT model for image classification task like this:

```
model = ViTForImageClassification.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k")

# Define a new sequential module for the classifier
new_classifier = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(768, 256), # First layer with 256 neurons
    nn.ReLU(), # Activation function
    nn.BatchNorm1d(256),# Batch normalization for the first layer
    nn.Dropout(0.1), # dropout
    nn.Linear(256, 64), # Second layer with 64 neurons
    nn.ReLU(), # Activation function
    nn.BatchNorm1d(64), # Batch normalization for the second layer
    nn.Dropout(0.1), # dropout
    nn.Linear(64, 2) # Output layer with 2 neurons
)
model.classifier = new_classifier
```

Then I trained the model using Trainer() class from hugging face and saved the best model in a checkpoint.
when loading the trained model from this checkpoint I get this warning:

```
Some weights of the model checkpoint at /content/best_models_complex/checkpoint-564 were not used when initializing ViTForImageClassification: ['classifier.8.weight', 'classifier.6.running_var', 'classifier.2.running_mean', 'classifier.6.num_batches_tracked', 'classifier.6.weight', 'classifier.4.bias', 'classifier.2.running_var', 'classifier.2.num_batches_tracked', 'classifier.6.bias', 'classifier.8.bias', 'classifier.2.bias', 'classifier.2.weight', 'classifier.0.weight', 'classifier.0.bias', 'classifier.6.running_mean', 'classifier.4.weight']
- This IS expected if you are initializing ViTForImageClassification from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing ViTForImageClassification from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
Some weights of ViTForImageClassification were not initialized from the model checkpoint at /content/best_models_complex/checkpoint-564 and are newly initialized: ['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']
You should probably TRAIN this model on a downstream task to be able to use it for predictions and inference.
```

And the predictions of the model are very bad (probably because of the random weights of the added layers)
So my question is **how to load the model from the checkpoint with the weights of the new layers not being ranodm?**

Comment: I wonder how Trainer() can load the best model at the end of the training correctly if loading the model from a checkpoint is not working properly.